# How to trigger a function after tweening in ROBLOX

Tags: lua, roblox

Does anybody know how to trigger a function call after tweening? I want to show some text after the tween stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweens come with a [Completed](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/TweenBase/Completed) event, and you can attach a callback to it.

In a LocalScript, you can have something like this :

```
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")

-- find your GUI element to animate
local lp = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local exampleScreen = Instance.new("ScreenGui", lp.PlayerGui)
exampleScreen.Name = "Example"
local label = Instance.new("TextLabel")
label.Position = UDim2.new(0,0,0,0)
label.Size = UDim2.new(0, 10, 0, 10)
label.Parent = exampleScreen

-- choose some properties to animate
local goal = {}
goal.Position = UDim2.new(0.5, -20, 0.5, -100)
goal.Size = UDim2.new(0.5, 40, 0.5, 200)

-- create the tween
local time = 5 --seconds
local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(time)
local tween = TweenService:Create(label, tweenInfo, goal)

-- listen for when the tween is finished
tween.Completed:Connect( function(tweenState)
    label.Text = "Tween Completed"
end)

-- play the tween
tween:Play()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question! I'm a beginner to game dev and i've heard Roblox game dev isn't that hard so i give it a try! btw, Have a nice Day!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the tween time in tweeninfo variable. Just make it wait() for the same time as the tween takes to play() and then trigger a function.

Comment: `local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")`
`local part = script.Parent`

`local Text = game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.DefTXT`

`local info = TweenInfo.new(10, Enum.EasingStyle.Linear, Enum.EasingDirection.InOut, 0, false, 0)`
`local tween = TweenService:Create(part, info, {Position = Vector3.new(-15.736, 0.5, -75.14)})`

`tween:Play()`
`wait(10)`
`Text.Visible = true`

is this what you meant?